# How to allow a group of user to unlock page which is locked by author except admin user

Tags: aem, jcr

I have author rights in AEM. I have locked a page. when i am trying to unlock page by login as different user then, how can i unlock the page?

Is there any way that a group of users can unlock page which is locked by different user.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [there](http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2012/06/06/cq5-5-members-of-administrators-group-not-able-to-unlock-pages-from-other-users/) and [there](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/UnlockALockedPage.html) only user **admin** can unlock pages, locked by other user.